# Multiply quantity with price and display total

Tags: c#

In the gridview i have an edit button when i click that the two fields will change to textboxes quantity and total.. when the user edits the quantity total has to be calculated automatically and display the result in the total field.. but i am getting the error in the line

```
decimal price= Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("$",  String.Empty).Replace(",", String.Empty));
```

input string was not in a correct format
here is the code

```
protected void txtQuantity_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtQuantity = (TextBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)txtQuantity.NamingContainer;
    TextBox txtTotal = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtTotal");
    decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("$",  String.Empty).Replace(",", String.Empty));
    decimal total = price * Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text);

    txtTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:C}", total);
}
```

Comment: And your first course of action should have been to check the string and verify that it is what you expect it to be instead of asking a question here. Come on, this is very basic debugging!

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Try additionally removing all whitespace with `Regex.Replace(yourString, "\s*")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
decimal price = decimal.Parse(row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", ""));
```

Comment: Why do you think changing `String.Empty` to `""` would effect? `String.Empty` is equal to `""`. From it's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _The value of this field is the zero-length string, ""._

Comment: I thought the meaningful difference may be using `decimal::Parse` instead of `Convert::ToDecimal`. I just wrote the `""` because that's how I like to write it.

Comment: even using after using parse i am getting the same error

Comment: `Convert.ToDecimal(String)` method is equivalent to use `Decimal.Parse(String)` with current culture. That doesn't change anything. Same as changing  `String.Empty` to `""` doesn't effect anything.

Comment: How to calculate the total (quantity * price )